# ASP.NET 5 on windows 2008 HttpPlatformHandler error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I can connect to IIS default web site but can not get response from my custom site.It's a **ASP.NET 5(rc1)** application on the **windows 2008** server.There are no connecting log in IIS log.

[image]

Any idea?

**Update**
After few hours. I got this 
[image]

I find error in event log

[image]

And a related discuss on [IISIntegration](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/79). Still looking for solution now

Comment: try restarting the IIS.

Comment: I restart the server and IIS not help

Comment: First things first - can you run ANY site on your IIS. Start with a basic just HTML site, if successful - next try a dummy/basic ASP.NET site, containing basically nothing, and so on. You need to identify which component/service is actually the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your 2008 server** (I can't remember the source link)

**The way to find problem:**
In your publish folder **wwwroot** there is a web.config. Change `stdoutLogEnabled` to true and you can got log in stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log".

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600" ></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In **approot** folder there is a web.cmd run it and check what happen

And you need to know:

[In beta8 and rc1 ASP.NET Core Applications hosted in IIS employed a native IIS module, HttpPlatformHandler v1.2, to forward requests to the ASP.NET Core Kestrel Server.](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105)
https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/79